# Derive the solution to $\frac{dQ}{dt} = kQ$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

> Derive the solution to $\frac{dQ}{dt} = kQ$ in terms of $Q_0$

Here is my work:

$\frac{dQ}{dt} = kQ$

$\frac{dQ}{Q} = kdt$

$\int\frac{dQ}{Q} = \int kdt$

$lnQ = kt + C$

$Q = e^{kt}e^{C}$

**Did I derive this correctly?** The only thing I'm unsure about is the notation $Q_0$. What does it mean and how is it different from $Q$? Does it affect my answer?

Comment: Thats fine; you can also call $e^C = B$ or call it anything else as it is just a constant of integration.

Comment: what is $Q_0?$ it looks like the value of $Q$ at $t = 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct.

Presumably, $Q_0$ refers to the value of $Q$ at $t = 0$ (the text should specify somewhere).  It would then follow (given your work) that
$$
Q_0 = Q(0) = e^{k\cdot 0} e^{C} \implies\\
Q_0 = e^C
$$
So, we can write
$$
Q(t) = Q_0 \,e^{kt}
$$
Which is likely the solution they have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln | Q|=kt+C \implies  Q =Ae^{kt}.$$
$$Q(0)=A=Q_0 \implies Q=Q_0e^{kt}$$